# How do I set http errors in fast api for this code?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have created a table class and schema for sql table and I want to return an error with a status code. Can you tell me where I went wrong?

```
@app.get("/employees", response_model=List[EmployeeSchema])
   async def read_data(conn:LegacyCursorResult=Depends(get_db)):
   temp = conn.execute("select * from Employee;")
   results_as_dict = temp.mappings().all()
   print(results_as_dict)
   temp2 = list(conn.execute("select * from Employee;"))
   print("temp", temp2)
   username = [i[3] for i in temp2]
   print(username)
   password = [i[4] for i in temp2]
   print(password)
   if not ( username ):
       raise HTTPException(
           status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
           detail={"detail":"user not found"},
       )
   return results_as_dict
```

Comment: I'd also like to point out that there is absolutely no need to run your query twice, and there shouldn't be any need to do the manual conversion to a dict. `cursor = conn.execute("...")` and `cursor.fetchall()` with the fetch mode set to dictionary (depending on which library you're using) should be enough by itself.

Answer (score 0):

How about using 404 insterad of status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND

```
@app.get("/employees", response_model=List[EmployeeSchema])
   async def read_data(conn:LegacyCursorResult=Depends(get_db)):
   temp = conn.execute("select * from Employee;")
   results_as_dict = temp.mappings().all()
   print(results_as_dict)
   temp2 = list(conn.execute("select * from Employee;"))
   print("temp", temp2)
   username = [i[3] for i in temp2]
   print(username)
   password = [i[4] for i in temp2]
   print(password)
   if not ( username ):
       raise HTTPException(
           status_code=404,
           detail="user not found",
       )
   return results_as_dict
```

Or do you mean something like this:

```
@app.get("/employees/{employee_name}")
async def read_item(employee_name: str):
    employees = conn.execute("select * from Employee;")
    results_as_dict = employees.mappings().all()
    if employee_name not in results_as_dict :
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Employee not found")
    return {"employee": results_as_dict[employee_name]}
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when I enter wrong username

Comment: What response do you get? 200?

Comment: yes, I get response 200

Comment: Will it not always return 200 as it is just loading all users in the database and the only time it will return 404 is when there are no users in the db?

Comment: how do I make it give http error when username is wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what you actually want this route to do? Is it return a User given a username?

Comment: this route gets all usernames and passwords from the table. In react.js, i use this api for login. i want to have http errors for wrong username

Comment: How can you get “wrong username” if the endpoint needs to return ALL usernames?